# Time frame for displaying user count is not working in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I am having a dashboard which shows the user created / deleted count of today, yesterday, this week, this month etc;
For this they wrote a condition in controller to get these counts and also scopes in model.
The above scenario is working fine in Rails 3.2 but not working in Rails 4.2. 
This is my code:

controller:

```
  protected
  def get_user_counts(conditions = {})
    includes = []
    if conditions.empty?
      # nothing
    elsif conditions.keys.first.include?("accounts.")
      includes = [:account]
    end

    result = []
    [
      {:label => 'today', :start => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, :end => Time.zone.now.end_of_day},
      {:label => 'yesterday', :start => 1.days.ago.beginning_of_day, :end => 1.days.ago.end_of_day},
      {:label => 'this week', :start => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, :end => Time.zone.now.end_of_week},
      {:label => 'last week', :start => 7.days.ago(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week), :end => 7.days.ago(Time.zone.now.end_of_week)},
      {:label => 'this month', :start => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, :end => Time.zone.now.end_of_month},
      {:label => 'last month', :start => Time.zone.now.prev_month.beginning_of_month, :end => Time.zone.now.prev_month.end_of_month},
    ].each do |time_frame|
      result << [time_frame[:label], User.includes(includes).where(conditions).only_deleted.deleted_between(time_frame[:start], time_frame[:end]).count, User.includes(includes).where(conditions).with_deleted.created_between(time_frame[:start], time_frame[:end]).count]
    end

    return result
  end
```

model:

```
  scope :created_between, lambda { |start_at, end_at|
    { :conditions => {'users.created_at' => (start_at..end_at)} }
  }
  scope :deleted_between, lambda { |start_at, end_at|
    # Don't forget to use 'count_only_deleted' or 'find_only_deleted' in combination
    # with this, or you'll always return zero users.  :with_deleted and :only_deleted
    # keys do not work in named_scope.
    { :conditions => {'users.deleted_at' => (start_at..end_at)} }
  }
```

Is there any wrong in my code or need any modifications, especially in model scope? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with scopes.Eager loading of scopes in Rails 4 has been restricted.

You can change your scope like this :

```
scope :created_between, -> (start_at, end_at) { where(created_at: (start_at..end_at)) }
```